# Exiting the Arena

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

With the Bounty Hunter faction there came a possibility of battling in an arena.
**How can I quit the arena after I win?** I've only been able to 'mass retreat'; however, I'd like just to return to the BH base and take on a different challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it was changed by an update, since I haven't noticed it in the change logs, but last time I won an arena challenge the game asked me whether I want to 'run back to my mommy ship' or to try a different challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The [patch notes for v1.503](http://www.spacepiratesandzombies.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=2875) (posted on March 20th) include the line:

> Warp out location popup on exit Arena event.

This looks like the change that fixed your issue.